# sorting a concatenation of sorted arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, timsort

What is the sorting algorithm most optimized for sorting an array that consists of 2 sorted sub-arrays?

This question came up when I was solving: https://leetcode.com/problems/squares-of-a-sorted-array/

My solution is as follows:

```
    def sortedSquares(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        n = len(nums)
        l, r = 0, n-1
        res = [0] * n
        
        for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
            if abs(nums[l]) > abs(nums[r]):
                res[i] = nums[l] ** 2
                l += 1
            else:
                res[i] = nums[r] ** 2
                r -= 1
        return res
```

However this solution beats mine:

```
    def sortedSquares(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        return sorted([i * i for i in nums])
```

If timsort is doing insertion sort on small chunks, then wouldn't an array like this cause O(n^2) on half the runs? How is that better than my supposedly O(n) solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Its hard to say when you dont show your solution. Maybe there is some fundamental part of your code that makes yours slow.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I added my code and clarified.

Comment: Trying to beat the performance of an highly optimized C code with pure Python isn't easy.

Comment: @Matthias That makes sense to me.. Thank you!!

Comment: There are two other things. First: in the worst case, Timsort takes O(n log ⁡ n) comparisons to sort an array of n elements. Second: your algotithm doesn't work. I just put in some random list like `[2, -4, 0, 3, 5, -7, -5]` and got `[0, 16, 4, 9, 25, 49, 25]` as a result. Even an input with non-negative values like `[4, 3, 0, 2, 1]` will not give you a correct result.

Comment: I just see that I missed the point of the pre-sorted input. In that case the algorithm is correct, but still not able to compete with lovingly handcrafted C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the theoretical time complexity is O(n) because you don't need to sort at all (merely merge two ordered lists).  Performing a sort generally has a O(NlogN) complexity.

Complexity and performance are two different things however.  Your O(n) solution in Python code is competing with O(NlogN) in highly optimized low level C code.  In theory there should be a point where the size of the list is large enough for the Python based O(n) solution to catch up with the O(NlogN) profile of the native sort but you can expect that this would be a very large number of elements (probably larger than your computer's memory can hold). If Python's native sort is smart enough to switch to a radix sorting algorithm for integers or if its sorting algorithm benefits from partially sorted data, it will be impossible to catch up.